# Why is Django csrf_token permanent

Tags: django

From the documentation, I found django use a permanent, not session based csrf cookie. But if I look at the source html of the web page in which a form locates, I can see the hidden input which means I can get csrf cookie. If the cookie is permanent, I can forge a POST request with the cookie. Is that it?

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/contrib/csrf/#how-it-works

Comment: @petkostas So the crsf token changes or not? I don't get it from the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is changed after login/logout. You can check it with JQuery by getting in from cookie:

```
document.cookie.match(/csrftoken=([\w]+)/)
```

And try to compare it after relogin.